# General absolute/relative URL in CSS

Tags: html, css, macos, fonts

The is a pretty general question however I have read so many conflicting statements here and elsewhere that I am looking for something a bit more verified.

The problem started when my client noticed that a font was not loading on their website. Now this font is loading fine on PC but does not load on any Mac browsers. Additionally, this font is 1 out of 4 font-faces that I am loading on the page. So this in it's self confuses me.

But anyways, my question is around this problem. In an effort to make my CSS more strict to determine if this is the cause (although as mentioned, all other font-faces load correctly) I have amended the path to my font files. My first change was the capitalization of the folder from Fonts to fonts in the hope that this would get around any quirks that Mac browsers may have. Secondly, I worked on the file locations (which always were just as in my second example below).

The setup:

The css sits in a folder on the root domain called styles (public_html/styles/styles.css)

The fonts sit in a folder on the root domain called fonts (public_html/fonts/chevin-bold...)

I changed the capitalization of the folder from Fonts to fonts in the hope that this would get around any quirks that Mac browsers may have.Now some recommend that the path should be as below, with a ".." indicating that it needs to go back a folder.

The CSS:

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'ChevinBold';

src: url('../fonts/chevin-bold.eot');

src: url('../fonts/chevin-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),

     url('../fonts/chevin-bold.woff') format('woff'),

     url('../fonts/chevin-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),

     url('../fonts/chevin-bold.svg#ChevinBold') format('svg');

     font-weight: normal;

     font-style: normal;

}
```

And others recommend that the ".." should be avoided like the plague:

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'ChevinBold';

src: url('/fonts/chevin-bold.eot');

src: url('/fonts/chevin-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),

     url('/fonts/chevin-bold.woff') format('woff'),

     url('/fonts/chevin-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),

     url('/fonts/chevin-bold.svg#ChevinBold') format('svg');

     font-weight: normal;

     font-style: normal;
```

}

Now, before I ask the client to test and hope that this resolves the problem of this one font on Macs, what is the general consensus on which on to use? And failing that since I don't own a Mac, anyone using a Mac that can check it out for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend relative paths, using `..`, mainly because it's very common to move assets like images and CSS to a CDN, and you may not always have the opportunity to use `/`, especially if your CDN assets are in a subdirectory. With relative paths, it's much easier to use the same CSS files, with no processing, both for your local test environment and production.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Jacob, it is greatly appreciated. Will go ahead with relative paths and hopefully this resolves the font issue on Macs